# What cause Magento Cloud CLI account login keep on failing?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, magento2, php-7.0

I set up new environment on a new computer and installed magento cloud cli. And try to login to cloud account by running `magento-cloud login` but the link for `http://127.0.0.1:5000` always return 
`This site can’t be reached`

so I did alternative login and run this command: `magento-cloud auth:password-login` to login to my cloud account and I won't be able to login. It always return 
Login failed. Please check your credentials.

```
Please log in using your Magento Cloud account.
Your email address or username: myemail@company.com
Your password:

Login failed. Please check your credentials.

Forgot your password? Or don't have a password yet? 
Visit:https://accounts.magento.cloud/user/password
```

I'd like to know why it always failing is there anything I missed ?
I have tried so many times and I am really sure that the credentials I have entered was correct. Also the 
I followed the magento documentation for environment setup: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/setup/first-time-setup.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found that after changing my password on the Magento account side (I had a space " " in my password) this fixed it. Not sure if there was something specific with my terminal and the way it sends passwords?